# android - how can i use the "android:layoutDirection"?

Tags: android, android-layout

it seems that android 4 provides **"android:layoutDirection"** for linearLayout and **"android:textDirection"** for textView , but when i choose them , i get a compilation error that it doesn't recognize them like that:

`error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layoutDirection' in package 'android'`

i also can't find out more information on the internet about those attributes. what do they mean, and how come i can't use them?

Comment: Your question has been asked as a part of this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/9262667/1321873 and has been answered.

Comment: yea, i used this part of the question which i can't solve it! and that answers didn't solve my problem. So, how can i solve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It works if you change your project properties to API Level 17.

Answer (score 9):

May be help u.

```
Note: To enable right-to-left layout features for your app, you must set supportsRtl to "true" and set targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher.
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2