# Concatinating Arabic and English text android TextView

Tags: android, localization, textview

I have the following algorithm to be able to concatenate Arabic text and English text

```
private String getFormatedArabicEnglishMessage (String [] parts) {

    String retString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {

        if (MyServices2Utils.isProbablyArabic(parts[i]) == true) {
            retString += "\u202B" + new String(" ") + "\u202C";
            retString += "\u202B" + new String(parts[i].getBytes()) + "\u202C";
            retString += "\u202B" + new String(" ") + "\u202C";
        } else {
            retString += " ";
            retString += parts[i];
            retString += " ";
        }   
    }

    return retString;
}
```

but is is not working in all cases :

in case of default locale == ar I got the following results :

[image]

in case of default locale == en I got the following results :

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If I understood it right, your problem is that whenever the `Locale` is not arabic, the append method adds text to the right instead of to the left, which is the way of writing arabic texts (from right to left).

If this is the issue, you'll have to check for the `Locale` and if it's not arabic, you'll need to set this property to the `TextView` or whatever you're using:

```
android:textDirection="anyRtl"
```

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3atextDirection) for more info.

Comment: I got this message on console : No resource identifier found for attribute 'textDirection' in package 'android'

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634414/android-how-can-i-use-the-androidlayoutdirection

Comment: Yes, sure, I forgot to ask what API where you using, sorry. Is it working now?

Comment: it doesn't work and it give me the same results of English locale

Comment: What have you exactly added?

Comment: 1) android:textDirection="anyRtl" in my TextView Properties 

2) Change API level to 17 

3) add supportRTL= true in the manifest file

Comment: If you change it to `textDirection="rtl"` does it work if the `Locale` is different than AR?