# iOS arabic localization issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, arabic-support

I have a string which contains an arabic string. When device locale is in arabic, the string is displayed properly. But when device locale is in english, the string order is lost i.e it turns the string to rtl.

My localizable string is:

```
"%1$@ has recharged your phone by %2$@."
```

When locale is in english the output is:

[image]

The output should have been:

برتيكشا has recharged your phone by 1500.

How do I do this?

Comment: There is a similar question in android:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215740/concatinating-arabic-and-english-text-android-textview

Comment: Please refer this link-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130853/how-to-force-an-app-to-change-language-in-ios-objective-c/34131794#34131794

Comment: I have separate localizable files for arabic and english. Only problem occurs when the device locale is english and the parameter that I have to pass contains arabic string.

Comment: It is not possible JMS

Comment: Thank you. There is no other way?

Comment: No other way for this.

Comment: Refer my above link.If my answer is useful, please up vote my answer.

Comment: OK, thank you. I'll try it out.