# android - how can i use the “android:layoutDirection”? - again

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

can someone help me how can i use this attribute `android:layoutDirection` ,

and please don't refer me to this question [What is the status of Right To Left languages on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9262667/1321873) because it doesn't answer my question!

Comment: You shouldn't need to repost an exact question that you already have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634414/android-how-can-i-use-the-androidlayoutdirection
I suggest you read the Android SDK documentation before posting further questions.

Comment: thanks for your replay, but what can i do there is no one answer my question! so i decide to repost it.

i'll read the documentation and if there is a solution i'll post it.
thanks again.

Comment: You should bump the other post with whatever you have found or more data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

layoutDirection is not be published in 4.0,so you cannot use the attr,but if you not be using sdk,but build with all code of android.
first get the Linearlayout in your code when it created,normally after setContent,and using @hide api setLayoutDiredtion(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LOCALE),which define in View.java
,of course,after 4.2 you can use layoutDirection in xml directly