# How to render RTL text correct on older Android versions

Tags: android, right-to-left, hebrew, bidi

I've used Google Translate to translate the following string "I think CompanyXYZ is a great company in 2014 and beyond" to Hebrew and this resulted in [image]

When I display this text in a TextView on a Galaxy S3 (Android 4.3), I get [image]

which seems to be correct.

When I run the same program on a Galaxy Tab 7 (running Android 2.2), I get [image]

which is obviously not correct.

Can I use android.support.v4.text.BidiFormatter and/or java.text.Bidi to render this correct?
When running the following code

```
    Bidi bidi = new Bidi(text, Bidi.DIRECTION_DEFAULT_RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    for (int i = 0; i < bidi.getRunCount(); i++)
    {
        int start = bidi.getRunStart(i);
        int level = bidi.getRunLevel(i);
        int limit = bidi.getRunLimit(i);
        Log.d("RTL", "bidi.run["+i+"] = "+start+";"+level+";"+limit+";"+ text.substring(start, limit));
    }
```

I do get the following 5 runs

```
bidi.run[0] = 0;1;9;אני חושב 
bidi.run[1] = 9;2;19;CompanyXYZ
bidi.run[2] = 19;1;36; היא חברה גדולה ב
bidi.run[3] = 36;2;40;2014
bidi.run[4] = 40;1;46; ומעבר
```

Hence all the information seems to be available to render this string correct but I don't know how to proceed. Can I use BidiFormatter? Or should I override TextView.draw()?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I realize it's been a while...

I made a function for my app which gets bidirectional strings, depending on the main direction which I thought would be helpful.

```
public static String getBidiString(String input, int direction) {
    boolean rtlContext;
    int defaultBidiDirection;
    if (direction == Bidi.DIRECTION_LEFT_TO_RIGHT) {
        rtlContext = false;
        defaultBidiDirection = Bidi.DIRECTION_DEFAULT_LEFT_TO_RIGHT;
    } else /* if (lang == Util.Lang.HE) */{
        rtlContext = true;
        defaultBidiDirection = Bidi.DIRECTION_DEFAULT_RIGHT_TO_LEFT;
    }

    Bidi bidi = new Bidi(input,defaultBidiDirection);
    if (!bidi.isMixed()) return input;



    BidiFormatter bidiFormatter = BidiFormatter.getInstance(rtlContext);
    StringBuilder bidiTestBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < bidi.getRunCount(); i++)
    {
        int start = bidi.getRunStart(i);
        int level = bidi.getRunLevel(i);
        int limit = bidi.getRunLimit(i);
        String run = input.substring(start, limit);

        if (level != direction) {
            run = bidiFormatter.unicodeWrap(run,!rtlContext) + " ";
        }
        bidiTestBuilder.append(run);
    }

    return bidiTestBuilder.toString();
}
```

the `direction` parameter should be either `Bidi.DIRECTION_LEFT_TO_RIGHT` or `Bidi.DIRECTION_RIGHT_TO_LEFT` depending on the default direction of the text.

I certainly am not claiming that I implemented this completely correctly, but this code works for my use cases.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I apply this function to the test string I used in my question (on the Galaxy Tab 7 GT-P1000, running Android 2.3 in the meantime) , I still see 4102 iso 2014

Comment: Note that I'm using android.support.v4.text.BidiFormatter, not android.text.BidiFormatter

Comment: I'm also using the support version of BidiFormatter. I'm not sure what the issue is, but you can check the line `run = bidiFormatter.unicodeWrap(run,!rtlContext) + " ";` That's where text that is opposing the default direction is wrapped.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Rendering on your 2.2 device is not incorrect. The difference is that the paragraph direction is LTR. It is very common to set paragraph orientation "by context", which means - according to the first bid I run. But it is legitimate to set the direction otherwise. For example, Windows textbox allows the end user switch this direction by pressing <kbd>left ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd> or <kbd>right ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd> (left or right shift, does not matter). Usually, alignment follows this direction.</s>

Official support for RTL layout direction was introduced in 4.2. But even before, since 2011 (it seems to be 4.0.1), there has been a `@hide` method [View.setLayoutDirection()](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blame/6d7475d666baefaa3ba9f0dcee25238739454241/core/java/android/view/View.java#) *credits to [Du Shunpeng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1381309/du-shunpeng), who published his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13837822/192373) a year ago*.

Unfortunately, 2.2 is even older, and this non-public API was not available. Consider using WebView, it does support **dir=rtl** for **div** and text input.

Note that even back then, the ME versions of Android, including the Tab 7 device, were often customized by the manufacturer or distributor to provide some level of BiDi support, so it's important to test on the device that will be used by your audience.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm surprised by your "not incorrect" statement. I at least assumed that the 4012 (iso 2014) is incorrect. Given the information returned by java.txt.Bidi, I would assume that rendering the text 'correct' would be not too difficult, eg. in TextView.onDraw(), but I'm not sure that's the way forward. I also use canvas.drawText occasionally for performance reasons so using WebView as a general solution is not an immediate option.  I will try it though.

Comment: OMG. missed the 4102 in your screenshot. _Mea culpa_.

Comment: If this text is a static label, I would prefer `TextView` subclassing. But if it is text input, I would suggest WebView. And don't miss the case of localized devices.

Answer (score 0):

I think below code can help you

```
public static Spannable getRtlBidiString(String input)
{
    return getBidiString(Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(input), Bidi.DIRECTION_RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
}

public static Spannable getForceRtlBidiString(String input)
{
    return getForceBidiString(Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(input), Bidi.DIRECTION_RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
}

public static Spannable getRtlBidiString(Spannable input)
{
    return getBidiString(input, Bidi.DIRECTION_RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
}

public static Spannable getLtrBidiString(Spannable input)
{
    return getBidiString(input, Bidi.DIRECTION_LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
}

public static Spannable getLtrBidiString(String input)
{
    return getBidiString(Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(input), Bidi.DIRECTION_LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
}

public static Spannable getBidiString(Spannable input, int direction)
{
    boolean isRtl;
    int baseDirection;
    TextDirectionHeuristicCompat heu;

    if (direction == Bidi.DIRECTION_LEFT_TO_RIGHT)
    {
        isRtl = false;
        baseDirection = Bidi.DIRECTION_LEFT_TO_RIGHT;
        heu = TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.FIRSTSTRONG_LTR;
    }
    else  /* if (lang == Util.Lang.HE) */
    {
        isRtl = true;
        baseDirection = Bidi.DIRECTION_RIGHT_TO_LEFT;
        heu = TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.FIRSTSTRONG_RTL;
    }

    Bidi bidi = new Bidi(input.toString(), baseDirection);

    if (!bidi.isMixed())
        return input;

    BidiFormatter bidiFormatter = BidiFormatter.getInstance(isRtl);
    SpannableStringBuilder bidiBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < bidi.getRunCount(); i++)
    {
        int start = bidi.getRunStart(i);
        int level = bidi.getRunLevel(i);
        int limit = bidi.getRunLimit(i);

        CharSequence run = input.subSequence(start, limit);

        if (level != baseDirection)
        {
            run = bidiFormatter.unicodeWrap(run, heu, !isRtl).toString();
        }

        bidiBuilder.append(run);
    }

    return bidiBuilder;
}

public static Spannable getForceBidiString(Spannable input, int direction)
{
    boolean isRtl;
    int baseDirection;
    TextDirectionHeuristicCompat heu;

    if (direction == Bidi.DIRECTION_LEFT_TO_RIGHT)
    {
        isRtl = false;
        baseDirection = Bidi.DIRECTION_LEFT_TO_RIGHT;
        heu = TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.ANYRTL_LTR;
    }
    else  /* if (lang == Util.Lang.HE) */
    {
        isRtl = true;
        baseDirection = Bidi.DIRECTION_RIGHT_TO_LEFT;
        heu = TextDirectionHeuristicsCompat.ANYRTL_LTR;
    }

    Bidi bidi = new Bidi(input.toString(), baseDirection);

    if (!bidi.isMixed())
        return input;

    BidiFormatter bidiFormatter = BidiFormatter.getInstance(isRtl);
    SpannableStringBuilder bidiBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < bidi.getRunCount(); i++)
    {
        int start = bidi.getRunStart(i);
        int level = bidi.getRunLevel(i);
        int limit = bidi.getRunLimit(i);

        CharSequence run = input.subSequence(start, limit);

        if (level != baseDirection)
        {
            run = bidiFormatter.unicodeWrap(run, heu, !isRtl).toString();
        }

        bidiBuilder.append(run);
    }

    return bidiBuilder;
}
```